# Can I save a shortcut of a folder when I use Device File Explorer in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 1, I know I can use  Device File Explorer in Android Studio to display all files in an Android device.

But there are many files and folders in the Diagram, you can see Image A.

How can I save a shortcut of a folder ?  Such as I hope to save *data -> data -> com.hicac.chattest* to a shortcut, so I can access it quickly.

**Image A**

[image]

Comment: Did you try to drag that folder to the desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible as the shortcut you create will not reflect any changes made on running the app, you can copy the file and keep it on your desktop.

One workaround I use when having to access the device explorer multiple times is, I expand the folders and keep it open, so as long as the physical device/emulator is connected/running, the device explorer tab when clicked will show you the expanded state of the files/folders, thus saving the hassle to re expand it again and again.